# What is the best solution to support i18n in modular Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, intellij-idea

I am working on modular Spring application. It has few modules. One of them has two sub modules: `web` and `jar`. These modules have separated messages properties basenames.

The first has declared bean with id `messageSource`. I know that in the application can exist only one bean with messageSource id. The second one has bean with another name (similar to `messageSource`) and has declared own class which extends `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`.

I have read here: http://blog.synyx.de/2010/04/modular-web-applications-based-on-spring/ about one solution. Here https://github.com/synyx/messagesource is solution for storing messages in database.

I wonder: what is the best solution to support i18n in modular Spring application? I would like to have one directory with messages properties files. Not separate directory for each module. Can I configure Spring to get access to messages over modules?

I am using IntelliJ IDEA to work with application modules.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to me you don't need two separate properties file in your application. You can have a single directory for property files and can use that in all your modules. Just place all your property files in web under resources folder or i18n whatever you want. Then create a bean in your xml for messageSource.

Now you can define your classes in jar module with @Component annotation and there you can have an @Autowired field of ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource type.

I think this would resolve your query. Cheers.